# highcharts rendering wrong on reload page with (only in chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, jsf, highcharts

That's difficult to explain, but here I go.
I have one highchart chart in a JSF system.
On the first time the page is loaded, it renders perfectly.
But if I try to load again the same page, the chart renders wrong.
That happens only in chrome. In firefox it works just well.

On the browser's console, I got this error:

Uncaught Highcharts error #16: www.highcharts.com/errors/16

Any ideas?

Comment: This has to do with browser's cache.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about this possibility.
When because chrome works with a temp variables store, so it tries to reuse the same variable for the chart when reloaded, but I don't know how to solve this problem.
Do you have any clue?

Comment: Try these two headers:
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");  #Expires sometime in the past
header("Cache-control: no-cache");                 #Disables caching

Comment: Try to add some condition which checks whether the `window.Highcharts` is defined, then if it's not - load Highcharts. It will prevent loading the Highcharts twice.